# How to convert NSString to bytes

Tags: nsstring

`NSString *test = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

How to convert this string to bytes?

Answer (score 25):

```
NSData *bytes = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: let me explain what is the NSData ?

and what is the  NSString.. how it differ from string(in java) ?

Comment: And for the actual bytes, `uint8_t *rawBytes = [bytes bytes]`

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like this:

```
NSString *test=@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
NSUInteger bytes = [test lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%i bytes", bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 1.x**

```
extension String {
    var bytes: [Byte] {
        return Array(utf8)
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 2.1.1**

```
extension String {
    var bytes : [UInt8] {
        return Array(utf8)
    }
}
```

---

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var bytes: [UInt8] { return .init(utf8) }
    var data: Data { return .init(utf8) }
}
```

---

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var bytes: [UInt8] { .init(utf8) }
    var data: Data { .init(utf8) }
}
```

---

testing:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".bytes  // [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
```