# How to convert NSString to bytes array

Tags: java, objective-c, nsstring, arrays

I want to convert a NSString to bytes array. This is what i do on Java:

```
private static final String myString = ">9:2212!>3415!2345611<::156:66>12:6569;6154!<2!6!!:32!!>!943252<3:1;:>214964?6?;!?6:343564:64!93";

byte byteArr[] = toBytes(myString);

static byte[] toBytes(String s) {
        int size = s.length();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[size / 2];
        int i = 0;
        for(int j = 0; i < size; j++)
        {
            bytes[j] = (byte)((s.charAt(i) & 0xf) << 4 | s.charAt(++i) & 0xf);
            i++;
        }

        return bytes;
 }
```

This returns me something like: [b3k2da311

I tried to use [myString UTF8String], but it basically returns the same string. I need something like the code above.

Comment: What encoding do you want the bytes to be in? UTF8,16,32 ASCII?

Comment: UTF8.

dataUsingEncoding and UTF8String probably are not what i am looking.

Comment: I think you want UTF-16BE - Android's strings are UTF16 BE

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881482/nsstring-into-bytes-array  The conversion required is not a simple "convert NSString to UTF-8"  Look at the Java code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be taking the lowest four bits of each character in the string and packing them into the byte array.  It seems a bit bizarre to me, but this is the direct translation (without the bug :) ).

```
static NSString* const myString = @"whatever";

// In some method

// Class methods are roughly equivalent to static methods in Java
NSData* byteArray = [[self class] toBytes: myString];

// Method definition
// The result is encapsulated in a NSData to take advantage of ARC for memory management
+ (NSData*) toBytes: (NSString*) aString
{
    NSUInteger size = [aString length];
    NSMutableData bytes = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: size / 2];
    // Get a pointer to the actual array of bytes
    uint8_t* bytePtr = [bytes mutableBytes];
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    // NB your code had a bug in that an exception is thrown if size is odd
    for (NSUInteger j = 0 ; j < size / 2 ; ++j)
    {
        bytePtr[j] = (([aString characterAtIndex: i] & 0xf) << 4)
                   | ([aString characterAtIndex: i + 1] & 0xf);
       i += 2;
    }
    // NSMutableData is a subclass of NSData, so return it directly.
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` has a method call `UTF8String` that returns `const char *`:

- (const char *)UTF8String

You can find the documentation here:

[NSString Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHCCED)

Comment: Tried it before, but it basically returns the same string.

`NSString *myString = @">9:2212!>3415!2345611<::156:66>12:6569;6154!<2!6!!:32!!>!943252<3:1;:>214964?6?;!?6:343564:64!93";
    NSLog(@"myString: %s", [myString UTF8String]);`

myString: >9:2212!>3415!2345611<::156:66>12:6569;6154!<2!6!!:32!!>!943252<3:1;:>214964?6?;!?6:343564:64!93

Answer (score 0):

You might want to spend a little time understanding character encodings so that this isn't voodoo magic. ;-)

`NSData* data = [theString dataWithEncoding: NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
const char* bytes = (const char*)data.bytes;`