# How to convert String to byte in Swift？

Tags: swift, string, nsdata

How to convert String to byte in Swift？
Like `String .getBytes()`in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert NSString to bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881482/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-bytes)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can iterate through the UTF8 code points and create an array:

```
var str = "hello, world"
var byteArray = [Byte]()
for char in str.utf8{
    byteArray += [char]
}
println(byteArray)
```

Comment: [(Byte)] is not identical to to 'UInt8'

Comment: @xaxxon in what way is it not?

Comment: @JoeDaniels I have no clue.  I'm not even sure I wrote that.

Answer (score 129):

There is a more elegant way.

**Swift 3:**

```
let str = "Hello"
let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
```

**Swift 4: (thanks to @PJ_Finnegan)**

```
let str = "Hello"
let buf: [UInt8] = Array(str.utf8)
```

Comment: I don't know why I put in `var buf`, might as well be `let buf`

Comment: Definitely the best way.

Comment: Apparently not working in Swift 4. Use `var buf : [UInt8] = Array(str.utf8)` instead.

Answer (score 13):

edit/update: **Xcode 11.5 • Swift 5.2**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var data: Data { .init(utf8) }
    var bytes: [UInt8] { .init(utf8) }
}
```

---

```
"12345678".bytes   // [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]
```

Answer (score 3):

String.withCString is the peer to Java's String.getBytes(void). Use it like this (extra typing added):

```
let s = "42"
s.withCString {
  ( bytes : (UnsafePointer<CChar>) ) -> Void in
  let k = atoi(bytes)
  println("k is \(k)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, for when you need to be able to pass to C-library functions:

```
let str = hexColour.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let x = strtol(str!, nil, 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

`string.utf8` or `string.utf16` should do something like what you are asking for. See here for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1.**

It depends what you want to achieve.  For the same question, I used...

```
let message = "Happy"
for v in message.utf8 {
    print(v)
}
```

I then performed the operations I needed on the individual byte.  The output is:

```
//72
//97
//112
//112
//121
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.utf8view